# VBA web data not showing entire table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to download the table into an Excel sheet then loop through to the next table.The loop is working(very slow though) but I am only getting the top of the page up(the top 5 lines Dog Name trainer name etc) and the main table does not appear.I also get the Cookie message up.
Any Suggestion most welcome:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()


 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  Range("A1").Select

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim e As integer
    Dim myurl As String, shorturl As String
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

i = 1
Do While i < 3


 myurl = "URL;http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id=" & i & ""


  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=myurl,   Destination:=Range("$A$1"))


  .Name = shorturl
  .FieldNames = True
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .PreserveFormatting = True
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .RefreshPeriod = 0
  .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
  .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
  .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
  .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
  .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
  .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
  .WebDisableRedirections = False
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
  .WebDisableRedirections = False
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

  Columns("A:J").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("K1").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,   SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
  Columns("A:J").Select
  Range("J1").Activate
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
  Columns("A:J").Select
  Selection.ColumnWidth = 20.01
  Columns("B:B").Select
  Selection.ColumnWidth = 20.01
  Rows("1:9").Select
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove




  i = i + 1

 Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The table data is loaded via an `ajax` request after the initial page load.

If you look at the page in chrome and open the `developer tools (F12) -> Network Tab`.  You will see an additional request for the following [url](http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_form.sd?dog_id=2):
`http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_form.sd?dog_id=`

The method you are using to retrieve the data is slow.  One way to speed it up would be to request the url's via an `xmlhttprequest` and parse the corresponding data you need yourself.

Here is an example of an `xmlhttprequest` (note that the data returned is a string of the source code that you can then parse):

```
Function XmlHttpRequest(url As String) As String
    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", url, False
    xml.send
    XmlHttpRequest = xml.responseText
End Function
```

So requesting data via this method would look something like this:

`response = XmlHttpRequest("http://www.somesite.com")`

This is probably the fastest method i know to retrieve data from a website since it doesn't involve actually rendering anything.

Then to parse any given data you need to look for things in front or behind the data that are consistent in the source.  (Usually divs with specific class names or something like that).  A generic parse might look like this:

```
loc1 = instr(response,"MyClassName")
loc1 = instr(loc1, response, ">") + 1 'the exact beginning of the data i'd like
loc2 = instr(loc1, response, "</td>")' the end of the data i'd like
data = trim(mid(response,loc1,loc2-loc1))
```

Finally here are all the methods you could paste in to get something up and running.  I'm not sure what fields you are exactly after so i just parsed a few from each page as examples:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetTrackData()
    Dim response As String
    Dim dogHomeUrl As String
    Dim dogFormUrl As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim dogName As String
    Dim dogDate As String
    Dim trainer As String
    Dim breeding As String
    Dim loc1 As Long, loc2 As Long

    dogHomeUrl = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id="
    dogFormUrl = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_form.sd?dog_id="
    x = 2
    For i = 1 To 10
        response = XmlHttpRequest(dogHomeUrl & i)
        Debug.Print (response)
        'parse the overall info

        'this is the basic of parsing the web page
        'just find the start of the data you want with instr
        'then find the end of the data with instr
        'and use mid to pull out the data we want
        'rinse and repeat this method for every line of data we'd like
        loc1 = InStr(response, "popUpHead")
        loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, "<h1>") + 4
        loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</h1>")
        dogName = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
        'apparantly if dog name is blank there is data to report on the web site
        If dogName <> "" Then
            'now lets get the dogDate
            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<li>")
            loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, "(") + 1
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, ")")
            dogDate = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
            'now the trainer
            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<strong>Trainer</strong>") + 24
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</li>")
            trainer = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

            response = XmlHttpRequest(dogFormUrl & i)
            'now we need to loop through the form table and parse out the values we care about
            loc1 = InStr(response, "Full Results")
            Do While (loc1 <> 0)
                Dim raceDate As String
                Dim raceTrack As String
                Dim dis As String

                loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, ">") + 1
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</a>")
                raceDate = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                raceTrack = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

                Range("A" & x).Value = dogName
                Range("B" & x).Value = dogDate
                Range("C" & x).Value = trainer
                Range("D" & x).Value = raceDate
                Range("E" & x).Value = raceTrack

                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "Full Results")
                x = x + 1
            Loop
            Debug.Print (response)
        End If
        'parse the form table

    Next i
End Sub
Function XmlHttpRequest(url As String) As String
    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", url, False
    xml.send
    XmlHttpRequest = xml.responseText
End Function
```

**Edit 1**

The data we were interating on was erroneous, Apparantly the first column isn't always a link.  Here is an amended example with more fields being parsed.  Let me know if you have any questions:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetTrackData()
    Dim response As String
    Dim dogHomeUrl As String
    Dim dogFormUrl As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim dogName As String
    Dim dogDate As String
    Dim trainer As String
    Dim breeding As String
    Dim loc1 As Long, loc2 As Long
    Dim qt As String
    qt = """"


    dogHomeUrl = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id="
    dogFormUrl = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_form.sd?dog_id="
    x = 2
    For i = 1 To 10
        response = XmlHttpRequest(dogHomeUrl & i)
        Debug.Print (response)
        'parse the overall info

        'this is the basic of parsing the web page
        'just find the start of the data you want with instr
        'then find the end of the data with instr
        'and use mid to pull out the data we want
        'rinse and repeat this method for every line of data we'd like
        loc1 = InStr(response, "popUpHead")
        loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, "<h1>") + 4
        loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</h1>")
        dogName = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
        'apparantly if dog name is blank there is data to report on the web site
        If dogName <> "" Then
            'now lets get the dogDate
            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<li>")
            loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, "(") + 1
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, ")")
            dogDate = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
            'now the trainer
            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<strong>Trainer</strong>") + 24
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</li>")
            trainer = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

            response = XmlHttpRequest(dogFormUrl & i)
            'now we need to loop through the form table and parse out the values we care about
            loc1 = InStr(response, "<td class=" & qt & "first" & qt) + 17
            Do While (loc1 > 17)
                Dim raceDate As String
                Dim raceTrack As String
                Dim dis As String
                Dim trp As String
                Dim splt As String
                Dim pos As String
                Dim fin As String
                Dim by As String
                Dim winSec As String
                Dim remarks As String
                Dim time As String
                Dim going As String
                Dim price As String
                Dim grd As String
                Dim calc As String

                loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, ">") + 1
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                raceDate = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                If InStr(raceDate, "<a href") > 0 Then 'we have a link so parse out the date from the link
                    Dim tem1 As Long
                    Dim tem2 As Long
                    tem1 = InStr(raceDate, ">") + 1
                    tem2 = InStr(tem1, raceDate, "</a>")
                    raceDate = Trim(Mid(raceDate, tem1, tem2 - tem1))
                End If
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                raceTrack = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td><span class=") + 16
                loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, ">") + 1
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</span>")
                dis = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td class=")
                loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, ">") + 1
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                trp = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                splt = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                pos = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<span class= " & qt & "black" & qt & ">") + 21
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</span>")
                fin = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                by = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<a href=") + 8
                loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, ">") + 1
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</a>")
                winSec = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                '<td><i>
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td><i>") + 7
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</i>")
                remarks = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                '<span class="black">
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<span class=" & qt & "black" & qt & ">") + 21
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</span>")
                time = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                '<td class="center">
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td class=" & qt & "center" & qt & ">") + 19
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                going = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td class=" & qt & "center" & qt & ">") + 19
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                price = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td class=" & qt & "center" & qt & ">") + 19
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
                grd = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

                Range("A" & x).Value = dogName
                Range("B" & x).Value = dogDate
                Range("C" & x).Value = trainer
                Range("D" & x).Value = raceDate
                Range("E" & x).Value = raceTrack
                Range("F" & x).Value = dis
                Range("G" & x).Value = trp
                Range("H" & x).Value = splt
                Range("I" & x).Value = pos
                Range("J" & x).Value = fin
                Range("K" & x).Value = by
                Range("L" & x).Value = winSec
                Range("M" & x).Value = remarks
                Range("N" & x).Value = time
                Range("O" & x).Value = going
                Range("P" & x).Value = price
                Range("Q" & x).Value = grd

                loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td class=" & qt & "first" & qt) + 17
                x = x + 1
            Loop
            Debug.Print (response)
        End If
        'parse the form table

    Next i
End Sub
Function XmlHttpRequest(url As String) As String
    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", url & "&cache_buster=" & GenerateRandom, False
    xml.send
    XmlHttpRequest = xml.responseText
End Function
Function GenerateRandom() As String
    GenerateRandom = Int(Rnd * 1000)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi weeksdev,not enough room for my response to your comments here so I have placed them in an "answer" above.

Comment: I have so far managed to get the following fields out of the table.

Comment: @colin i'll take a look at this later today/tomorrow if you haven't already solved.

Comment: Hi weeksdev,many thanks for that,have been working on it but only partly solved as you can see from my attempts :) :) :)..colin

Comment: is there anybody out there :)

Comment: @colin added an edit with a more complete example, hopefully this helps

Comment: Hi weeksdev,That's great many thanks for the revision and many thanks for the time and effort you have put into this.I have encountered a few problems the main one being that it seems to get stuck on the 4th dog history(Aarons Lad) when it hist that hsitory it just keeps repeating up until line 32,767.Coukld this have something to do with the loop.Secondly  the K column which is the BY Field keeps showing the line.. 2fracs14;,with the numbers either side changing from line to line.Other than those two probs the program works great any further suggestions much appreciated Kind regards Colin

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that great and detailed reply.I am relatively new to this and I have been working on your code and I have encountered a few problems when it comes to parsing from the source.I managed to get table fields distance,position,split time and fin fine but the rest I cant get.I extracted the source for each item and here is a list with the corresponding actions for the ones that worked to the right:
TOP
    Dog name

## Anglesey Flight

```
date of birth an sexb
<li>
 (3 Aug 2013)
 bk d </li>

trainer
<li><strong>Trainer</strong> J B Thompson</li>

breeding
<li><strong>Breeding</strong> Head Bound — Inshaarla</li>

FORM
DATE
>18Mar15</a> </td>            ' devweeks dev code works fine] 

TRACK
<td>BVue</td>                 '   devweeks dev code works fine] 



DIS
<td><span class="black">470m</span></td>  [here I did +25 and - 7 and     it     works] 

TRP
<td class="center">[2]</td>                   

SPLIT                                        [+4 works with this]
<td>4.51</td>

POS
<td>5555</td>                                [+4 works with this]

FIN
<td><span class="black">5th</span></td>      [ 25 - 7 works with this] 

BY
<td>12</td>

WIN/SEC
">Ballymac Fleetie</a> </td>

REMARKS
<td><i>Crd&amp;CkdW&amp;StruckInto1/4</i></td>

TIME
 <td><span class="black">28.67</span></td>
GOING
 <td class="center"> N</td>

PRICE
<td class="center">4/1</td>

GRADE
<td class="center">A5</td>

CALC
<td class="last right"><span>29.63</span></td>
 </tr>
```

For the remainder of the fields I am encountering different responses.For example the code for the fields POS(position) and SPLIT are + 4.But when I apply this to raceBY which is identical source to POS and SPLIT I get the following  result... td>13¾.
Also  with other fields I get... ( href="http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id=72970" onclick="return Html.popup(this, {width:800, height:480})" title="Click for Dog Form...">STORM FORCE...
Please see my code.
I have tried with all of the other fields and get variations of the above two messages.I know I must be doing something wrong here and any advice greatly appreciated.

```
         Option Explicit
         Sub GetTrackData()
    Dim response As String
    Dim dogHomeUrl As String
    Dim dogFormUrl As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim dogName As String
    Dim dogDate As String
    Dim trainer As String
    Dim breeding As String

Dim loc1 As Long, loc2 As Long

dogHomeUrl = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id="
dogFormUrl = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_form.sd?dog_id="
x = 2
For i = 1 To 10
    response = XmlHttpRequest(dogHomeUrl & i)
    Debug.Print (response)
    'parse the overall info

    'this is the basic of parsing the web page
    'just find the start of the data you want with instr
    'then find the end of the data with instr
    'and use mid to pull out the data we want
    'rinse and repeat this method for every line of data we'd like
    loc1 = InStr(response, "popUpHead")
    loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, "<h1>") + 4
    loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</h1>")


    dogName = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
    'apparantly if dog name is blank there is data to report on the web site
    If dogName <> "" Then
        'now lets get the dogDate
        loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<li>")
        loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, "(") + 1
        loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, ")")
        dogDate = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
        'now the trainer
        loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<strong>Trainer</strong>") + 24
        loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</li>")
        trainer = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))
        response = XmlHttpRequest(dogFormUrl & i)



        'now we need to loop through the form table and parse out the values we care about
        loc1 = InStr(response, "Full Results")
        Do While (loc1 <> 0)
            Dim raceDate As String
            Dim raceTrack As String
            Dim raceDis As String
            Dim racePos As String
            Dim raceSplit As String
            Dim raceFin As String
            Dim raceBy As String
            Dim raceTrp As String
            Dim raceRemarks As String
            Dim raceWinSec As String
            Dim raceTime As String
            Dim raceGoing As String
            Dim racePrice As String
            Dim raceGrd As String
            Dim raceCalc As String







           ' Dim raceBy As String
            'Dim raceBy As String
            'Dim raceWinSec As String

            loc1 = InStr(loc1, response, ">") + 1
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</a>")
            raceDate = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1)) ' weeksdevcode  works fine

            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
            raceTrack = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1)) 'weeksdevcode  works fine
            'ABOVE TWO WEEKSDEV CODE
            '..............................................................
            'BELOW ARE MINE
            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 25       ' column F = DISTANCE/works
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>") - 7
            raceDis = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

           loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4         'column G = POSITION/works
           loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
           racePos = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

           loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4         'column H = SPLIT/works
           loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
           raceSplit = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))


           loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 25        'column I =FINISH/works
           loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>") - 7
           raceFin = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

          'BELOW IS THE CODE FOR raceBy and raceRemarks
          'and by the side is the results.

        '  loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 4       '( here I get..13&frac34 and similar;)
         ' loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
         ' raceBy = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

         ' loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 7       '(Here I Geta href="http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id=72970" onclick="return Html.popup(this, {width:800, height:480})" title="Click for Dog Form...">STORM FORCE</a>
          'loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
         ' raceRemarks = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

          ' BELOW ARE 3 variations I tried on raceTrp

          'loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 18      'Here I Get.. <a href=""http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id=72970"" onclick=""return Html.popup(this, {width:800, height:480})"" title=""Click for Dog Form..."">STORM FORCE</a>"
          'loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
          'raceTrp = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

         ' loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "<td>") + 18       ' Here I Get.. <a href=""http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id=72970"" onclick=""return Html.popup(this, {width:800, height:480})"" title=""Click for Dog Form..."">STORM FORCE</a>"
          'loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>") - 6
          'raceTrp = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))

        '  loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "class=center")      'same as above
         ' loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, ">") + 19
          'loc2 = InStr(loc1, response, "</td>")
         ' raceTrp = Trim(Mid(response, loc1, loc2 - loc1))




            Range("A" & x).Value = dogName
            Range("B" & x).Value = dogDate
            Range("C" & x).Value = trainer
            Range("D" & x).Value = raceDate
            Range("E" & x).Value = raceTrack
            ' above weeksdev all works fine
            Range("F" & x).Value = raceDis
            Range("G" & x).Value = racePos
            Range("H" & x).Value = raceSplit
            Range("I" & x).Value = raceFin
            Range("J" & x).Value = raceBy
            Range("K" & x).Value = raceTrp
            Range("L" & x).Value = raceRemarks
            Range("M" & x).Value = raceWinSec
            Range("N" & x).Value = raceTime
            Range("O" & x).Value = raceGoing
            Range("M" & x).Value = racePrice
            Range("N" & x).Value = raceGrd
            Range("O" & x).Value = raceCalc







            loc1 = InStr(loc2, response, "Full Results")
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        Debug.Print (response)
    End If
    'parse the form table

   Next i
End Sub
Function XmlHttpRequest(url As String) As String
    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", url, False
    xml.send
    XmlHttpRequest = xml.responseText
End Function
```

Kind Regards
Col

Comment: I have so far managed to get the following fields out of the table.DIS eg(460m) FIN(eg 1st,2nd etc) POS(eg 1213), SPLIT(eg5.6) REMARKS(eg QAw,Ald) TIME(eg28.24).The Fields I cant seem to get at are TRP(eg[1]), BY(eg1.5),WIN/SEC(eg name of winner or second),GOING(eg N) PRICE (eg6/1) GRD(egA8) and CAL(eg 30.02).Another problem seems to be I can set up the code for one field but another field turns up.Any help greatly appreciated. Regards Col(jimmy)

Comment: Hi weeksdev,That's great many thanks for the revision and many thanks for the time and effort you have put into this.I have encountered a few problems the main one being that it seems to get stuck on the 4th dog history(Aarons Lad) when it hist that hsitory it just keeps repeating up until line 32,767.Coukld this have something to do with the loop.Secondly  the K column which is the BY Field keeps showing the line.. 2fracs14;,with the numbers either side changing from line to line.Other than those two probs the program works great any further suggestions much appreciated Kind regards Colin

Comment: Hi,Only had a chance to get to work this program last few days and it's proving very unpredictable.sometimes downloading a few files but most of the time coming up with the (not responding) message.Is there a way this file could be made more stable